# Can't extract ng-xi18n ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, angular, internationalization, angular-cli

I'm trying to add internationalisation to my Angular 2 project, and following the [intructions in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#).

I started the project using `angular-cli` and my `tsconfig.json` is in /src.

Running the command:

`./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n -p src/tsconfig.json`

I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/project/dist/out-tsc/src/app/_models/example.metadata.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1347:33)
    at MetadataWriterHost.writeMetadata (/home/project/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/compiler_host.js:164:22)
    at MetadataWriterHost.writeFile (/home/project/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/compiler_host.js:143:19)
    at Object.writeFile (/home/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:64240:132)
    at Object.writeFile (/home/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9020:14)
    at printSourceFileOrBundle (/home/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:61204:16)
    at emitSourceFileOrBundle (/home/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:61155:21)
    at Object.forEachEmittedFile (/home/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8986:17)
Extraction failed
```

And it's not wrong, the directory `/home/project/dist/out-tsc/src/app/` does not exist, instead it is `/home/project/dist/out-tsc/app/`. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm suspecting the outDir parameter in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "app/testing/*",
    "app/**/*.spec.ts",
    "test.ts"
  ]
}
```

If it is at all relevant `@angular/compiler-cli` and `@angular/platform-server` are both at version 2.4.10, and npm is giving me the following issues:

```
typescript@2.2.2  invalid
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.10
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.10
```

Comment: which angular-cli version are you on? the ng-xi18n is part of angular-cli.

Comment: angular-cli at version 3.10.10

Comment: There is no 3.10.10... the latest is 1.0.0

Comment: Sorry, I ran `npm --version -g angular-cli`. `ng version` tells me I'm at 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `ng xi18n`

I created a new angular-cli (version `1.0.0`):

```
ng new i18n-test
cd i18n-test
ng xi18n
```

Works just fine.

If this does not work, make sure your `package.json` has `dev-dependency`  `"@angular/cli": "1.0.0"`

then clean everything:

1. remove `node_modules` folder in your project.
2. remove `@angular/cli` global dependency `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
3. install it back `npm install -g @angular/cli`
4. install your project dependencies back `npm install`

Comment: It looks like that did it...no error message and I have the translation file `/src/messages.xlf`. What is the difference between `./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n` and `ng xi18n`? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: I believe it uses the same thing, not sure thou. if you try `ng --help` or `ng xi18n --help` to see all available flags.